# SPARK: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException while trying to load Big Graph in GraphX

Tags: java, scala, graph, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm trying to load a big Graph (60GB) using GraphX in spark1.4.1 in local mode with 16 threads. The driver memory is set to 500GB inside spark-defaults.conf.  I work on a machine that has 590341 MB free (shown by free -m command)which is actually 576GB.

Some details about the graph I'm trying to load: It is the Friendster Graph downloaded from snap.stanford.edu. The actual size is 30GB because Friendster is a directed Graph but I doubled the edges to create an undirected graph version. (That's why the size is doubled 60=2*30). I use the GraphLoader.edgeListFile using scala to load the Graph as shown below:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val logFile = "/home/panos/spark-1.2.0/README.md"
   // Create spark configuration and spark context
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My    App").setMaster("local[16]")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   val currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") // get the current directory
   val edgeFile = "file://" + currentDir + "/friendsterUndirected.txt"

   // Load the edges as a graph   
   val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,    edgeFile,false,1,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
 }
```

The problem is that the graph cannot be loaded receiving java.lang.negativeArraySize exception as shown below. I tried with smaller graphs (~4GB) with success. Any Idea?

```
16/01/10 13:04:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very    large size (440 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
16/01/10 13:32:56 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0  (TID 0)
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75)
at scala.reflect.ClassTag$class.newArray(ClassTag.scala:62)
at scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1.newArray(ClassTag.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.copyArrayWithLength(PrimitiveVector.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.resize(PrimitiveVector.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.$plus$eq(PrimitiveVector.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgePartitionBuilder$mcI$sp.add$mcI$sp(EdgePartitionBuilder.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:76)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(RDD.scala:703)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(RDD.scala:703)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/01/10 13:32:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75)
at scala.reflect.ClassTag$class.newArray(ClassTag.scala:62)
at scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1.newArray(ClassTag.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.copyArrayWithLength(PrimitiveVector.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.resize(PrimitiveVector.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.$plus$eq(PrimitiveVector.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgePartitionBuilder$mcI$sp.add$mcI$sp(EdgePartitionBuilder.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:76)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(RDD.scala:703)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(RDD.scala:703)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/01/10 13:32:56 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75)
at scala.reflect.ClassTag$class.newArray(ClassTag.scala:62)
at scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1.newArray(ClassTag.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.copyArrayWithLength(PrimitiveVector.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.resize(PrimitiveVector.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PrimitiveVector.$plus$eq(PrimitiveVector.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgePartitionBuilder$mcI$sp.add$mcI$sp(EdgePartitionBuilder.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:76)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$$anonfun$1.apply(GraphLoader.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(RDD.scala:703)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(RDD.scala:703)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Comment: I don't know what's happening in this case. But the "negative array size" makes me wonder if there is an integer arithmetic overflow somewhere. Is there, perhaps, an implicit assumption somewhere along the way that the array is small enough that computing its size doesn't cause an integer overflow? Sorry that I can't be more specific.

Comment: I saw similar posts with the same problem. There's an open GraphX bug:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5480